# How to record stream for exactly 30 seconds using python-vlc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc, libvlc, python-vlc

I'm trying to record an RTP stream via python-vlc for exactly 30 seconds but the output file is sometimes less than or greater than my desired video length.

Note: I tried using ffmpeg, but it can't properly decode the stream hence the decision to use python-vlc.

This is my code:

```
import vlc
import time

vlcInstance = vlc.Instance("--demux=ts")
player1 = vlcInstance.media_player_new()
media1 = vlcInstance.media_new("rtp://239.194.115.71:5000")
media1.add_option("sout=file/ts:sample.mpg")
limiter = 0

player1.set_media(media1)

player1.play()
time.sleep(1)

while player1.is_playing():
    if limiter > 30:
        player1.stop()
        media1.release()
        break
    limiter = limiter + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

What possible method can I use to always record the stream for exactly 30 seconds?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792218/saving-audio-from-livestream-using-vlc-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used opencv-python to get the current frame count and fps of the output file and used it to compute for the video length.

```
import vlc
import time
import cv2
import os.path

vid_len = 0
vlcInstance = vlc.Instance("--demux=ts")
player1 = vlcInstance.media_player_new()
media1 = vlcInstance.media_new("rtp://239.194.115.71:5000")
media1.add_option("sout=file/ts:sample.mpg")
player1.set_media(media1)

player1.play()

#checks if the length of the output exceeds 30 seconds
while vid_len < 30:
    time.sleep(1)
    #checks if the file exists and not empty
    if os.path.isfile('sample.mpg') and (os.path.getsize('sample.mpg') > 0):
        video_file = cv2.VideoCapture('sample.mpg')
        frames = int(video_file.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        fps = (video_file.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        vid_len = frames/fps

player1.stop()
media1.release()
```

[image: evid]